# Python converting date and time as pandas index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to convert my datetime column to be pandas dataframe index. This is my dataframe

```
    Date               Observed Min Max Sum Count
0   09/15/2018 12:00:00 AM  2   0   2   10  5
1   09/15/2018 01:00:00 AM  1   0   2   25  20
2   09/15/2018 02:00:00 AM  1   0   1   21  21
3   09/15/2018 03:00:00 AM  1   0   2   23  22
4   09/15/2018 04:00:00 AM  1   0   1   21  21
```

And I want the Date to be the index for the dataframe.

I've looked for answers and have tried this code

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S').strftime('%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
data = pd.read_csv('mandol.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=['Date'], index_col = 'Date', date_parser=dateparse)
data.head()
```

but the result is still error -> `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  AM`

how can I solve this?

Comment: `data.set_index('Date', inplace=True)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert the *Date* column and `set_index()` to set it as your dataframe index.

```
import pandas as pd

>>>df
    Date               Observed Min Max Sum Count
0   09/15/2018 12:00:00 AM  2   0   2   10  5
1   09/15/2018 01:00:00 AM  1   0   2   25  20
2   09/15/2018 02:00:00 AM  1   0   1   21  21
3   09/15/2018 03:00:00 AM  1   0   2   23  22
4   09/15/2018 04:00:00 AM  1   0   1   21  21

df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

>>>df
                     Unnamed: 0  Observed  Min  Max  Sum  Count
Date
2018-09-15 00:00:00           0         2    0    2   10      5
2018-09-15 01:00:00           1         1    0    2   25     20
2018-09-15 02:00:00           2         1    0    1   21     21
2018-09-15 03:00:00           3         1    0    2   23     22
2018-09-15 04:00:00           4         1    0    1   21     21
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `set_index()` method.

Answer (score 1):

We can set the index to be the `Date` column values converted with `to_datetime` (I'm using `pop` to get values of the `Date` column and remove it from the DataFrame at the same time):

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date'))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                     Observed  Min  Max  Sum  Count
Date                                               
2018-09-15 00:00:00         2    0    2   10      5
2018-09-15 01:00:00         1    0    2   25     20
2018-09-15 02:00:00         1    0    1   21     21
2018-09-15 03:00:00         1    0    2   23     22
2018-09-15 04:00:00         1    0    1   21     21
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code, it sets the second column (Date) as index and transforms it with the standard datetime parser provided by pandas.to_datetime:

`ds = pd.read_csv('mandol.csv', sep=';', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)`

`parse_dates=True` automatically transforms the index to a pandas Datetime object.